# Multiple Tab apps, using authorization of a single app id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

All,

Here is the scenario;

- Our website uses APPID-1 for auth and extended permissions (MainSite)
- Our Page Tab App uses APPID-1 for auth & extended permission
  (TabApp-1), and this adds the auth_token to our DB on MainSite

However we want to add another tab that uses APPID-1 for auth_token acquisition, is this possible?

Proposed scenario;

- MainSite - APPID-1 acquire auth_token
- TabApp-1 - APPID-1 acquire auth_token
- TabApp-2 - APPID-1 acquire auth_token

I should note that non of our TabApps actually need the auth_token, its our MainSite backend app that uses the auth_token to perform actions for the user. However we want to make it easier for our users to use the site, and many come via our Fan Page.

So can we have TabApp-2 pop the Auth Dialog for APPID-1 with is not TabApp-2's APPID?

Specs:
Ruby on Rails 3.1 and using Graph API & Javascript Fb API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would have to initiate the JS SDK in TabApp-2 with APPID-1. Server-side you would receive a signed_request with TabApp-2 credentials but you can just it that if you work only with the JS API.

I guess you could validate the assumption with a prototype in less than 30 minutes. Have you done that yet? If so, what were the results?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different apps for this (but i think you're aware of that) the same app can be installed onto multiple pages, and you can show different content on each page by checking the  `page` parameter in the `signed_request` which is POSTed to your server when the page tab is loaded by a user.

As far as authorisation goes, you may have issues when getting the user to log in directly from a page tab (issues = it may not be allowed to redirect the user back to the tab after login because the full URL to the tab (`http://www.facebook.com/pages/somepage/12345?sk=app_{app id here}`) isn't 'owned' by your app)

If that happens you can send them to your main site after login with an additional parameter that you use to detect that the user started login on a page tab, and redirect them back to it

Comment: I am aware of the 1app multiple tabs. We actually have that running. However I need multiple tab canvases, and pop the authorization dialog for the same APPID.  The login redirect works just fine on multiple pages with the same app. The user gets sent back to the same page & app on that page. So thats not an issue.  Just need to have multiple canvases but using the same APPID thats my sticky part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'multiple canvases' in that context - could you clarify?

Comment: Each Facebook app can only have 1 Facebook Tab Canvas URL.  I need the ability to have 2 canvas URLs, so I mush create 2 Facebook apps. However I only want to authorize 1 APPID.

Comment: It might be possible to use a second app as effectively just an iframe into a website running using the first app's ID, but i suspect you'll come across an authentication issue if you try to redirect the user there directly from the auth dialog - you may need to send them to the first app's canvas and then manually redirect to 'app 2'

Answer (score 0):

Seems you will have to make a few apps, then just use php-sdk to authenticate, since the auth will be server side it will not matter what iframe or page tab it appears in, it will be able to auth to a single app.